# Polygons not showing in Google Fusion Table map

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I have a KML of Brazilian states that renders correctly in Google Earth. However, when I load the KML in Fusion Tables two of the states will not show up. The original data was in shapefile format and was simplified and converted to KML in QGIS. Are there limits to the number of vertices on Fusion Table?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by using v.generalize (Grass command from QGis processing plugin). Now the kml renders correctly in Fusion Tables